# How to add id and title in php url

Tags: php, url

I have the url which is working fine with sub_id but now i want to modify the url and i want to show 'sub_categories_name' along with 'sub_id'. But, 'sub_categories_name' is just like dummy i.e it is of no use, if a person search only with 'sub_id' then it will show the result.

I have tried something like this but the page is not showing any data

```
<?php 
  $categories_name = $_GET['categories_name'];
  $result = "SELECT * FROM sub_categories where 
    categories_name='$categories_name'";
    $data =mysqli_query ($conn, $result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    { 

      $sub_categories_name = $row['sub_categories_name'];
      $sub_id = $row['sub_id'];

        $sub_categories_name  = urldecode($sub_categories_name );  
        $sub_categories_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $sub_categories_name); 

        $url = '/classified/' . urlencode($sub_id) . '-' . urlencode($sub_categories_name);

    ?>
<a href="/classified/1-Health-and-Beauty">
    <div class="cat-box p-0 m-0 cat-url">
        <p class="subcat-url"><?php echo $sub_categories_name;?></p>
    </div>
</a>
<?php }?>
```

When my url is like  'http://localhost/classified/1', it is showing the data but when my url is like 'http://localhost/classified/1-Health-and-Beauty', it is not showing any data. I just want to show data on this also.

here is my `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/classified/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]
```

actually generated source code snippet of the HTML links. (browser view source) is like

```
<a href="/classified/1-Health-and-Beauty">
    <div class="cat-box p-0 m-0 cat-url">
        <p class="subcat-url">Health and Beauty</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance, Please help me out.

Comment: So split your `1-Health-and-Beauty` into category id and subcategory.

Comment: sorry, i am not getting you. Can you elaborate something more

Comment: `intval('1-Health-and-Beauty')` is `1`

Comment: can you please elaborate to some more extent @ Quasimodo's clone

Comment: I've not further investigated you code, but `http://localhost/classified/1` and `'http://localhost/classified/1-Health-and_Beauty'` only differ in the part after `1`. So `intval('1') === intval('1-some-title')` - both are integer `1`.

Comment: *"When my url is like 'http://localhost/classified/1', it is showing the data"* As far as I could see in a quick review, you do not show how you route / analyse the URL, but the *generation*.

Comment: i have removed the previous link parts through .htacces using  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54842052/edit) and add your .htaccess rewrite part to your question. Also add the actually generated source code snippet of the HTML links. (browser view source)

Comment: i have edited my code @Quasimodo'sclone clone

Comment: Is the .htaccess located in the `/classified` folder? If so, `intval($_GET['sub_id'])` does work on an url like `/classified/1-test`

Comment: yes, .htaccess located in the /classified folder

Comment: Currently you have `<a href="1">`, this should work anyway as you said.

Comment: yes,<a href="1"> is working but <a href="/classified/1-Health-and-Beauty"> is not working

Comment: sorry, please check my new edits

Comment: <a href="/classified/1-Health-and-Beauty"> is showing in source page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, somewhere in your project you must have a decision on `$_GET['sub_id']`. If you use `intval($_GET['sub_id'])` instead, everything after the number will be cut off.

Based on `mod_rewrite` you could alter your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+) category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]
```

meaning 1 or more digits at the begin of the current URL part based on the folder, ignoring anything which follows after the digits.

Comment: can you help me something more

Comment: i want to print sub_id after sub_categories_name